# limit $ \lim_{x\rightarrow3}\left(\frac{x+1 - \sqrt{5x+1}}{\ln(\frac{x}{3})}\right) $

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

I am trying to find the limit of
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow3}\left(\frac{x+1 - \sqrt{5x+1}}{\ln(\frac{x}{3})}\right) $$

the function is continuous for all $ x \in \mathbb{R^+} $ except for $ x = 3 $ since then the denominator will be 0. $ (\ln(3/3) = \ln(1) = 0) $

I am trying to get rid of the term $ \ln(\frac{x}{3}) $ so that the denominator will no longer be 0 when x is 3. So that I can continue the function at point $ x = 3 $. But so far I haven't been able to find a solution. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. How do I go about finding the limit here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you've written the formula correctly?  Currently the limit doesn't exist, because the numerator doesn't vanish at $x=3$.

Comment: I would suggest to 1) Find a guess of the limit, using for instance the "de l'Hospital rule" 2) Rewrite the function with the change of variable $x = 3+y$, and use standard Taylor series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: I am sure, I am trying to continue the function, x = 3 doesn't belong in the domain of the function as the function is then undefined, but if I can somehow get rid of the ln term in the denominator, I can continue the function at that point, for example multiply the denominator and the nominator with a value such that the function will now be defined for x = 3

Comment: thanks Laurent, I will do that

Comment: Indeed, I believe now that the square in $(x+1)^2$ might be removed, at least the numerator would vanish then. Your numerator is 12 at the present time, thus the limit is $\pm \infty$. Whatever you do to the denominator. Would you have $x+1 - \sqrt{5x+1}$, then the problem would be more interesting

Comment: Without the square, I find the limit $\frac{9}{8}$

Comment: how do you get rid of the square, can you post an answer?

Comment: @Gravity. Square is gone. happy now? Let's get to work here...

Comment: well the question was with the square but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your revised expression, both numerator and denominator approach zero as $x$ approaches $3$. L'Hôpital's rule may therefore be applied, and we get an equal expression for your limit:

$$\begin{align}
 \lim_{x\to 3}\left(\frac{x+1 - \sqrt{5x+1}}{\ln(\frac{x}{3})}\right)
 &= \lim_{x\to 3}\left(\dfrac{1 - \dfrac 1{2\sqrt{5x+1}}\cdot 5}
   {\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{x}{3}}\cdot\dfrac 13}\right) \\[2 ex]
 &= \lim_{x\to 3}\left(1 - \frac 5{2\sqrt{5x+1}}\right)\cdot x \\[2 ex]
 &= \left(1 - \frac 5{2\sqrt{5\cdot 3+1}}\right)\cdot 3 \\[2 ex]
 &= \left(1 - \frac 58\right)\cdot 3 \\[2 ex]
 &= \frac 98
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

What you have is called an **indeterminate** equation.  The reason is that **both** the numerator and denominator go to zero (at the limit).  To solve this kind of problem, you have to take the derivatives of the numerator and denominator, **separately**, until one of them becomes a constant, then you substitute the 3 for x to find the value at the limit.